# get route params in asyncData after router push

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get the route params in the asyncData method, it works if I go manually to the route, but if I use router Push method, it doesn't get any params.

this is my asynData method:

```
  async asyncData(ctx) {
    const { id } = ctx.app.router.currentRoute.params
    await ctx.store.dispatch('user/GET_USER', id)
    return {
      user: ctx.store.state.user.user
    }
  },
```

and this is how I navigate to the respective page:

```
goToEdit(id) {
  this.$router.push({ path: `/users/${id}/edit` })
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(ctx)` can you see the params?

Comment: it returns the context with the params of the previous route.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to get route from ctx directly. [Here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/) a list of context arguments

```
 async asyncData({ route }) {
    const { id } = route.params
    await ctx.store.dispatch('user/GET_USER', id)
    return {
      user: ctx.store.state.user.user
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it in a similar way but I retrieve params and almost everything from `context`.

```
async asyncData(context) {
        const plans = await context.$axios.get("business/get-plans", {
            params: {
                currency: context.query.currency
            }
        }).then((res) => {
            return res.data;
        });
```

Take a look to `context.$axios` and `context.query`.